# How to center horizontally stretched grid item that has max-width

Tags: css, css-grid

I came across a requirement, to always center/stretch grid items (grid items have `max-width` set).

By default, they are stretched and there's `auto-fill`, so it works fine (they fill the whole column).

However when I hit a particular breakpoint and only one item goes into the row, and because item's `max-width` is smaller then columns width, it cannot stretch more. So I thought that I could use `margin: auto` on items, however when I do this, then items are no longer stretched (background color indicates that).

So is there a way to center horizontally stretched grid item that has max-width and is smaller then column it is in?

Example (please run in full page mode):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  background-color: green;
}

.container > div {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  /* margin: auto; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
  <div>Element 4</div>
  <div>Element 5</div>
  <div>Element 6</div>
  <div>Element 7</div>
  <div>Element 8</div>
</div>
```

and : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1uznck

Comment: Your "*[mcve]*" code must be contained within the question, whether as a runnable snippet or as code block(s). The external live demo is appreciated, but it doesn't replace the requirement for code to be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have breakpoints and you can control everything here is a roundabout it that will center the `divs` for you. I used `transform` and moved the divs to the middle. Does that work in your app. I'm not really sure.

That's how it looks for me. is that what you are trying to do. If not please let me know.

[image: thats how it looks]

```
div {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```